# Why do I need to create a sharedInstance for audio?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, singleton

In my code, I initialized two singletons. I have `var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance` and `var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance`. I then `setActive(false)` for the second singleton. Why do I need to create the second one? Instead of creating the second singleton, why can't I just set the first singleton to `setActive(false)`?

I believe it's because singleton's can have only one instance per class; however, I am just turning off the audio session, so I don't understand why I need two singleton's to do this.

```
@IBAction func recordAudio(sender: UIButton) {
    recordButton.enabled = false
    stopButton.hidden = false
    recordAudioOutlet.hidden = false

    //Get a file path to store the audio recording
    let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String

    let currentDateTime = NSDate()
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "ddMMyyyy-HHmmss"
    let recordingName = formatter.stringFromDate(currentDateTime)
    let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
    let filePath = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathArray)
    println(filePath)

    //Setup audio session
    var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: nil)

    //Initialize and prepare the recorder
    audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: filePath, settings: nil, error: nil)
    audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
    audioRecorder.record()
}

@IBAction func stopAudio(sender: UIButton) {
    //Stop recording the user's voice
    recordAudioOutlet.hidden = true
    audioRecorder.stop()
    var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance();
    audioSession.setActive(false, error: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand... Why do you think you need two singletons?

Comment: In fact, "two singletons" is a non-sequiter. `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()` will always return the one instance - the singleton.  Rather than calling `sharedInstance` twice you could save the reference from the first call in a property and use that, but because you are using local variables you need to get the reference a second time.

Comment: @Paulw11 it sounds like setting 'sharedInstance' as a global property instead of a local variable would resolve this for me?

Comment: There isn't really anything to resolve - there is only ever one AVAudioSession instance regardless of whether you retrieve it each time via `sharedInstance` or store a reference in your own property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AVAudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/AVAudioSession/sharedInstance) is a singleton process which cannot play (or record) 2 different audios.
If you start an audio from your app, the running audio (like if you're listening to music) will pause.
Why don't you make just one (maybe `class`) `variable` to manage the `AVAudiosession`?

If you create the variable 2 times, there's the same in it (because singleton always returns the same instance).